# How to make ListBox editable when bound to a List<string>?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, wpfdatagrid

**Edit**: The basic problem is binding a List to ListBox(or any other control). So I am editing the question.

I bound a list of string to a ListBox as below. However when I change the contents of the textbox it is not changing the string in the source list.Why?

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<string> _nameList = null;

    public List<string> NameList
    {
        get
        {
            if (_nameList == null)
            {
                _nameList = new List<string>();
            }
            return _nameList;
        }
        set
        {
            _nameList = value;
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        NameList.Add("test1");
        NameList.Add("test2");
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

And the XAML

```
 <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=main}" ItemsSource="{Binding NameList}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding .,Mode=OneWayToSource ,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `DataContext` of each `ListBoxItem` is the string itself, so the path of your binding is empty (`.`). `TwoWay` and `OneWayToSource` bindings require a path, since you can't just replace the current `DataContext`. So you need to wrap your string in an object that exposes the string as a property:

```
public class StringItem
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Expose the strings as a list of `StringItem`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<StringItem> _nameList = null;

    public List<StringItem> NameList
    {
        get
        {
            if (_nameList == null)
            {
                _nameList = new List<StringItem>();
            }
            return _nameList;
        }
        set
        {
            _nameList = value;
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        NameList.Add(new StringItem { Value = "test1" });
        NameList.Add(new StringItem { Value = "test2" });
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

And bind to the `Value` property:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=main}" ItemsSource="{Binding NameList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Note that `StringItem` will also need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that bindings are automatically updated. You should also expose the list as an `ObservableCollection<T>` rather than a `List<T>`

Comment: Thanks Thomas, great answer.  FYI, The code "public string class StringItem{}" confused me, could be an error.

Comment: @Jimmy, yes it was an error... I must have been distracted while typing this ;)

Answer (score 1):

May be it helsp?

```
<ListBox Name="lsbList">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: You can edit the UI like this, but the edit wont reflect in the list object

Comment: What do you mean? NameColumnField - list of your objects. For example, one of its properties has name Value. The Value is bound to TextBox in DataTemplate. And if you change it in textbox, it will not be changed in bounded object?

Comment: Also, please check the edited question where I come down to the actual issue.

Comment: +1, After reading Thomas's answer I understand what you are trying to say.+

Answer (score 0):

you can create a DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate with an itemscontrol and textboxes to edit your items

Comment: You can edit the UI like this, but the edit wont reflect in the list object

Comment: Please check the edited question. Even if I can edit the textbox in the UI it wont reflect in the source

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstand your question, it is pretty easy to implement. Look:

```
<ComboBox Text="My Comment 5 with addition." IsEditable="True" Height="25" Width="200">
        <ComboBoxItem>My comment1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>My comment2</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: You mid-understand, he wants the list items to be editable.