# How to edit ListBox items via IEditableCollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListBox`, which `ItemsSource` is bound to ViewModel's `ObservableCollection`.
Now I'm making a custom cotrol, which should manipilate `ListBox` items.
For instance, move items up/down.
I can't work with `ItemsSource`, because I want this control to work with variant data types, and I don't know what `Type` it will be.
All I know about `ItemsSource` type - it will be `IEnumerable`.
So I wrote code that uses `IEditableCollectionView` to swap adjacent items' property values.
It works fine if `ItemsSource` is an `ObservableCollection` of some complex type - `ObservableCollection<Customers>`.

```
private void ItemsSwapComplex(object originalSource, object originalDestination)
{
    IEditableCollectionView items = ListBoxToManage.Items;
    Type type = originalSource.GetType();

    // Create clones of Source and Destination
    // DOES NOT WORK WITH <string>
    dynamic cloneSource = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    dynamic cloneDestination = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    // Copy property values from Original to Clone
    PropertiesCopyComlex(originalSource, cloneSource);
    PropertiesCopyComlex(originalDestination, cloneDestination);

    // Copy new property values to the Source item
    items.EditItem(originalSource);
    object editSource = items.CurrentEditItem;
    PropertiesCopyComlex(cloneDestination, editSource);
    items.CommitEdit();

    // Copy new property values to the Destination item
    items.EditItem(originalDestination);
    object editDestination = items.CurrentEditItem;
    PropertiesCopyComlex(cloneSource, editDestination);
    items.CommitEdit();
}

private void PropertiesCopyComlex(object originalSource, object originalDestination)
{
    foreach (var v in originalSource.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        v.SetValue(originalDestination, v.GetValue(originalSource));
    }
}
```

But if `ItemsSource` is a collection of simple type, like `ObservableCollection<string>` - it throws an exception, that `string` doesn't have a constructor.
And I dont understand how to use `IEditableCollectionView` to edit simple string `ListBox` items.
This code does not affect `ItemsSource` at all:

```
IEditableCollectionView items = ListBoxToManage.Items;

items.EditItem(originalSource);
object editSource = items.CurrentEditItem;
editSource = "New string";
items.CommitEdit();
```

How do I use `IEditableCollectionView` to edit a single `string` item of `ItemsSource`?

UPDATE: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5806696/4826147) implies that my task is not possible. Must use a wrapper for string. And for my particular task - wrapper must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and have at least one, parameterless, constructor

Comment: A `string` is immutable and cannot be edited.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I use `IEditableCollectionView` to edit a single string item of `ItemsSource`?

You *cannot* edit a `System.String` because it's immutable, i.e. it cannot be modified after its creation.

[Why .NET String is immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365272/why-net-string-is-immutable)

If you use a mutable wrapper with a `string` property you can indeed modify the wrapper, but you can't assume that every type `T` that the enumerator returns is mutable.

Comment: OK, bu Im not trying to edit a string. Im trying to use `EditItem` and `CommitEdit` methods

Comment: On a `string`. Or what does *How do I use IEditableCollectionView to edit a single string item of ItemsSource?* mean? `Activator.CreateInstance` only works on types that have a default parameterless constructor, unless you know what arguments to pass it of course.

Comment: That means, that Im using `IEditableCollectionView`, which provides methods to `EditItem` and `CommitEdit` - and those methods don't work. `Activator.CreateInstance` is only the first part of code. The second part doest it in a different manner

Comment: So what is your current issue? Please modify your question and clarify your requirements.